# How can I write results from one CSV into another?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have these columns of prices in this prices.csv structured as follows:

```
         Date  price1  price2  price3  ...  price7  price8  price9  price10
   2018-10-18   11.49    7.32    7.31  ...   13.47    8.04  4.5055     9.67
   2018-10-19   11.51    7.29    7.29  ...   13.41    8.09  4.5149     9.71
   2018-10-22   11.47    7.29    7.26  ...   13.33    7.96  4.4772     9.65
   2018-10-23   11.48    7.31    7.28  ...   13.34    7.80  4.4583     9.52
   2018-10-24   11.58    7.35    7.23  ...   13.32    7.54  4.4206     9.27
```

I calculated the ratios of these prices using the following code:

```
cols = list(df.columns[1:])
for i,c in enumerate(cols[:-1]):
    for c2 in cols[i+1:]:
        df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)] = df[c]/df[c2]

        length = len(df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].index)
        start = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[0]
        end = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[length-1]
        change = str((end - start)/start)
```

This adds columns to the df like this:

```
price1/price2, price1/price3, price1/price4 ...
```

Which is perfect, however, I don't actually want new columns just the total returns of the ratio columns (calculated by "change") to be stored in results.csv in the following format:

```
    PAIR              RETURNS
price1/price2    0.012670773595482977 
price1/price3    0.06298657186450757
price1/price4    0.06786323591797078
     ...                 ...
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.read_csv("price1.csv")
fieldnames = ["PAIR", "RETURNS"]

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    cols = list(df.columns[1:])
    for i,c in enumerate(cols[:-1]):
        for c2 in cols[i+1:]:    
            df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)] = df[c]/df[c2]
            length = len(df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].index)
            start = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[0]
            end = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[length-1]
            change = str((end - start)/start)

            print(length)
            print(start)
            print(end)
            print(change)

            row = {"PAIR": df, "RETURNS": change}
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This code successfully places the "change"s into the right column but it doesn't correctly associate the pairs names to the rows. Also for some reason there are spaces between the rows:

[image]

EDIT2:
The output for print(df) and print(change) is as follows (keep in mind the values change as the for loop continues to run through:

```
0.06298657186450757
     Date      price1  price2  ...  price10  price1/price2  price1/price3
0  2018-10-18   11.49    7.32  ...     9.67       1.569672       1.571819
1  2018-10-19   11.51    7.29  ...     9.71       1.578875       1.578875
2  2018-10-22   11.47    7.29  ...     9.65       1.573388       1.579890
3  2018-10-23   11.48    7.31  ...     9.52       1.570451       1.576923
4  2018-10-24   11.58    7.35  ...     9.27       1.575510       1.601660
```

I need to find a way to isolate the headers in the df.

Comment: what do you mean by formatting isnt right? Can you post what output you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: How about simply 'df[['PAIR', 'RETURNS']].to_csv(file_path)'?

Comment: I considered that, although not sure how to implement it. Can I add it in at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question... but it seems like you already have the values for your column `"PAIR"` and your column `"RETURNS"` and the only thing you want it's to produce a `result.csv` with headers `"PAIR"` and `"RETURNS"` like this:

```
   PAIR              RETURNS
price1/price2    0.012670773595482977 
price1/price3    0.06298657186450757
price1/price4    0.06786323591797078
     ...                 ...
```

In python you can define a CSV file as a sort of "dictionary" where your **headers** are the **"keys"**, then, each row can be defined as a dictionary and you can associate each **value** in your row to it's **key header** like this:

```
import csv:

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["HEADER_1","HEADER_2"])
    row_1 = {"HEADER_1": "under header 1",
             "HEADER_2": "under header 2"}
    writer.writerow(row_1)
```

And you will get:

```
HEADER_1          HEADER_2
under header 1    under header 2
     ...                 ...
```

Your solution would be (I'm assuming you have a python list containing your pairs, another python list containing your returns, and both lists are the same length):

```
import csv

pairs = your_list_of_pairs
returns = your_list_of_returns
fieldnames = ["PAIR", "RETURNS"]

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for i in range(0, len(pairs):
        row = {"PAIR": pairs[i], "RETURNS":returns[i]}
        writer.writerow(row)
```

For dynamically using your code I think would be something like this:

```
import csv

pairs = your_list_of_pairs
returns = your_list_of_returns
fieldnames = ["PAIR", "RETURNS"]

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    cols = list(df.columns[1:])
    for i,c in enumerate(cols[:-1]):
        for c2 in cols[i+1:]:
            df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)] = df[c]/df[c2]

            length = len(df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].index)
            start = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[0]
            end = df['{}/{}'.format(c,c2)].iloc[length-1]
            change = str((end - start)/start)

            row = {"PAIR": df, "RETURNS":change}
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This looks good, however I don't have the lists, the pairs and returns are being calculated dynamically. The actual csv has over 1000 price columns. Would it be possible to write these pair names and results to the new CSV as part of the for loop?

Comment: Yes of course! generate your pairs inside your own for loop and them dynamically to the CSV file... Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks! Very close to working, but not quite. See the edit.

Comment: Can you print the value of `change` and `df` right before the line `row = {"PAIR": df, "RETURNS": change}` and add the output?

Comment: I posted an EDIT 2. Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: I figured out how to successfully associate the pair names to the change values by using: pair = df.columns[-1]  though its still skipping rows when writing to the CSV. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually was able to figure out the skipping lines with lineterminator = '\n' in the writer. I am now just missing the implementation of headers.

Comment: Acutally I figured everything out. haha sorry for the spam. Thank you so much for your help, couldn't have done it without you.